# Matlab Help code Script

Tags: matlab

I working with matlab, I have data row vector A 36000. I wold like cut this vector into matrix- the first column of the matrix must first 300 data samples of vector, and the second row must be the second 300 samples (301 to 600), and so on.  Please I need matlab script to do that, please any body can help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Just use `reshape` to reshape your vector into a matrix with 300 rows.

```
B = reshape(A, 300, []);
```

Also you switch up columns and rows in your question. THe example above places the data in column-major order. If you want row-major instead, then simply take the transpose.

```
B = reshape(A, 300, []).';
```

Comment: Ok, I will try, I have other question I working with ECG I used MIT - BIH Arrhythmia ECG, for example recording 100 lead 1 include about 2273 beats. I need cut these beats into rows of new matrix, but the important one I need center the r beaks in center of row in at 150th data number ? can some body help me to do that by matlam.  thank you advance.

Comment: @YakopYakopYakop That is a different question. If this answered your immediate question, accept the answer and open a new question.